# What's wrong with my api REST call OSB oracle service bus, jdeveloper

Tags: java, oracle, jdeveloper, servicebus, osb

I consume transbank API, with Oracle Service Bus (JDeveloper).
I need to call a method. I cannot do accept. Other methods do not have any problem. I do not know what is wrong with my configuration.
Does anyone know how to resolve this?

My configuration: [call service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRIl8.png)  and [request / response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4llP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Annoyingly when using REST adapter you can't use both template/query parameters and payload at the same time. To achieve this you will have to get creative with http adapter:
Manually setting relative URI
Manually setting method
nxsd translations
Manually setting content type